# How to loop on nested structure in golang?

Tags: go

I have a nested struct and I want to loop over this struct. Please help me how to loop over the struct to get the output in this format. I have mentioned the struct which I am using.

Expected Output:

```
    {  
    "PrefcatID":"PREF_001"
    "prefname: :"PREF_name"
    "PrefSubcategory":
        {
        "subcatid":"SUB_PREF_001",
        "PrefcatID":"PREF_001",
        "subcatname":"Sub Category Name 1"
     },
     {  
        "subcatid":"SUB_PREF_002",
        "PrefcatID":"PREF_001",
        "subcatname":"Sub Category Name 2"
     }
     }
```

Struct in Go:

```
    type PrefCategory struct {
    PrefcatID           string `json:"PrefcatID"`
    PrefName            string `json:"prefname"`
    Temp_PrefSubcategory []PrefSubcategory `json:"prefSubcategory "`
    }

    type PrefSubcategory struct {
    PrefcatID        string `json:"PrefcatID"`
    SubcatId         string `json:"subcatid"`
    SubCatName       string `json:"subcatname"`
     }
```

Comment: is the output JSON?

Comment: What's wrong with `encoding/json.Marshal`?

Comment: yes the output is json @zola

Comment: yes oakad. I have to do marshal...

Comment: stuck on how to proceed woth for _, range..

Comment: The expected output is not valid JSON.

Comment: There's no reason to loop. Just use [json.Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/). The docs have examples that do exactly what you want.

Comment: You haven't included any code with a for loop. How can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there but note that there are some syntax errors in your JSON example. The structs are almost there too, ultimately, you just need to build an instance of PrefCategory with the expected values and [marshal it to JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

```
type PrefCategory struct {
  PrefcatID            string            `json:"PrefcatID"`
  PrefName             string            `json:"prefname"`
  Temp_PrefSubcategory []PrefSubcategory `json:"prefSubcategory"`
}

type PrefSubcategory struct {
  PrefcatID  string `json:"PrefcatID"`
  SubcatId   string `json:"subcatid"`
  SubCatName string `json:"subcatname"`
}

func main() {
  pref := PrefCategory{
    "PREF_001",
    "PREF_name",
    []PrefSubcategory{
      {"SUB_PREF_001", "PREF_001", "Subcategory Name 1"},
      {"SUB_PREF_002", "PREF_001", "Subcategory Name 2"},
    },
  }

  jsonbytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(&pref, "", "  ")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(jsonbytes))
  /*
  {
    "PrefcatID": "PREF_001",
    "prefname": "PREF_name",
    "prefSubcategory": [
      {
        "PrefcatID": "SUB_PREF_001",
        "subcatid": "PREF_001",
        "subcatname": "Subcategory Name 1"
      },
      {
        "PrefcatID": "SUB_PREF_002",
        "subcatid": "PREF_001",
        "subcatname": "Subcategory Name 2"
      }
    ]
  }
  */
}
```